# NIP (French word for PIN) is not recognized by Google Assistant properly

Tags: actions-on-google, voice-recognition, voice

I am trying to add support for French-Canadian (fr-CA) and want the system to recognize the utterance for a PIN, which is required for control type applications.

For example, the English phrase of 'How do I know my PIN' would be this in french: "Comment puis-je savoir mon NIP".

aalso stating “un NIP” is always interpreted as “unique”, so that misses as well.

Comment: Can you add '... unique' as a training phrase so that it at least gets to the right intent?

Comment: yes, true.  thought I had done so.  just odd translation is all.  I'll try that.

Comment: This didn't solve it.  We are now also getting this:   mon NIP et un, deux, trois, quatre”… Google understands “mon lit” or ”Monique”.    Going to add those utterance translations as well and see.